# How to use the attribute 'url' of ol.source.OSM

Tags: django, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I've deployed a local openstreetmap tile server and tried many times to show the map using openlayers3, but failed unfortunately.
Here's my experiment scene.
I deploy the tile server on port 80, and get the image correctly via http://127.0.0.1:80/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png. Besides, I place a django web on port 8099, and i can access the web page via http://127.0.0.1:8099/my/page. In the template page, i wrote like this

```js
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
            attributions: [
                ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION
            ],
            url:'//127.0.0.1:80/osm_tiles2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'            
        })
    });

var map= new ol.Map({
        target : 'map_canvas',
        loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
        view: new ol.View({
            center:ol.proj.transform([116.391625,39.906813], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom : 12
        }),
        layers:[layer]
    });
```

The map_canvas shows nothing, but i can get the images from tile server in firebug.WHY?
Help me, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `crossOrigin: null` to the source, like so:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        attributions: [
            ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION
        ],
        url:'//127.0.0.1:80/osm_tiles2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        crossOrigin: null            
    })
});
```

Comment: Great. You might enjoy reading about the general problem this relates to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image